# DIVs overlapping with browser resize

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am converting an html page to a responsive page with a @media query without any framework.

Whenever I resize my browser window to a lower width, the `div`s are overlapping with each other.

First, I was using `position:absolute;`

but now I have removed `position:absolute;` but the `div`s are still overlapping with each other.

```
.demoD
{
width:100%;
position:relative;
display:flex;
margin-top:50%;
```

}

```
#demoD1 {
width:50%;
padding:40px 10px 20px 40px;
 }

 #demoD2{
width:50%;
background-color:#F3F6F7;
padding:80px 10px 30px 40px;    
  }
```

`divD2` is overlapping with `divD1`. Both `divD1` and `divD2` are placed in `divD`.

Please give me some solution.

Comment: add your `html` code too, and full `css`

Comment: Make sure you are targeting the correct class/ID, as the examples you've attached are mixed and `divD1` or `divD2` are not in them.
Also, maybe you should use `box-sizing: border-box;` to avoid overgrowing the set width.

Comment: We need to see more of the code, not just these snippets, to suggest a solution. Please share the full CSS, including the media query giving the result you've described.